# VHDL: Read input data in a loop

Tags: vhdl

I have state machine where I read 72-bit input data (8-bit command and 64-bit argument) in 8-bit chunks:

```
                when IDLE =>
                
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= C;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                   
                        cmd <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= IDLE;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';
                        cmd <= (others => '0');
                        argument <= (others => '0');
                    end if;
      
                ------------------------------------------
                when C =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A1;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(7 downto 0) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= C;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(7 downto 0) <= (others => '0');
                    end if;
                ------------------------------------------
                when A1 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A2;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(15 downto 8) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A1;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
                    end if;
                ------------------------------------------
                when A2 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A3;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(23 downto 16) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A2;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(23 downto 16) <= (others => '0');
                    end if; 
                ------------------------------------------
                when A3 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A4;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(31 downto 24) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A3;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(31 downto 24) <= (others => '0');
                    end if; 
                 ------------------------------------------
                 when A4 =>
                 if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                     cmd_st <= A5;
                     o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                     argument(39 downto 32) <= i_DataInput;
                 else
                     cmd_st <= A4;
                     o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                     argument(39 downto 32) <= (others => '0');
                 end if;
                ------------------------------------------
                when A5 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A6;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(47 downto 40) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A5;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(47 downto 40) <= (others => '0');
                    end if; 
                ------------------------------------------
                when A6 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= A7;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(55 downto 48) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A6;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(55 downto 48) <= (others => '0');
                    end if;                    
                ------------------------------------------
                when A7 =>
                    if i_DataAvailable_n = '0' then
                        cmd_st <= EXE;
                        o_DataGet <= '1';                        
                        argument(63 downto 56) <= i_DataInput;
                    else
                        cmd_st <= A7;
                        o_DataGet <= '0';                        
                        argument(63 downto 56) <= (others => '0');
                    end if;                    
                    

                when EXE =>
                    <... rest of the code ...>
```

Is in VHDL some more clever solution for it which doesn not require so many states? Kind of loop in which the incoming byte could append to the proper `argument` position?

Comment: We can see i_DataAvailable_n and o_DataGet provide handshaking. Provide a [mcve] here an entire entity/architecture pair, a testbench providing inputs and your readers can demonstrate alternatives (counters are FSMs for example, FSMs can be table driven, etc.). Otherwise your question is non-specific. By definition you'd have something with the same number of 'states' to distinguish between 9 input values.

Comment: Instead of a specifying each state in an enumerated type, you could specify the states in as bits in a counter or shift register.  You could then do some simple math based on that counter or shift register-stored state to reduce the clutter.

Another option is to place the repetitive code in a procedure and call the procedure with the correct offsets for each state.

Comment: Yes, you can operate a counter in a state to count n (bits/bytes/chunks) and roll states A1 to A7 into a single state.